# Generic Parameterized Base ViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I have following Base class for my ViewModels :

```
abstract class BaseViewModel<T, R>(private val schedulerProvider: BaseSchedulerProvider) :
    ViewModel() {

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    private val _liveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<T>>()
    val liveData: LiveData<Resource<T>>
        get() = _liveData

    protected abstract val requestObservable: Observable<R>

    protected abstract fun getSuccessResult(it: R): T

    init {
        Handler().postDelayed({
            sendRequest()
        }, 1)
    }

    fun sendRequest() {
        _liveData.value = Resource.Loading()
        composeObservable { requestObservable }
            .subscribe({
                _liveData.postValue(Resource.Success(getSuccessResult(it)))
            }) {
                _liveData.postValue(Resource.Failure(it.localizedMessage))
                Timber.e(it)
            }.also { compositeDisposable.add(it) }
    }

    private fun <T> composeObservable(task: () -> Observable<T>): Observable<T> = task()
        .doOnSubscribe { EspressoIdlingResource.increment() } // App is busy until further notice
        .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
        .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
        .doFinally {
            if (!EspressoIdlingResource.countingIdlingResource.isIdleNow) {
                EspressoIdlingResource.decrement() // Set app as idle.
            }
        }
```

Here is How I initialize ViewModel in Fragment :

```
class MainFragment @Inject
constructor() // Required empty public constructor
    : DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var factory: MainViewModel.Factory

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

            val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
}
```

As you see I have following in init block to delay :

```
Handler().postDelayed({
                sendRequest()
            }, 1)
```

Without this delay app crashes since api will be null in the inherited class :

```
    class MainViewModel(
        api: PokemonService,
        schedulerProvider: BaseSchedulerProvider
    ) : BaseViewModel<List<Pokemon>, List<NamedResponseModel>>(schedulerProvider) {

override val requestObservable: Observable<List<NamedResponseModel>> =
        api.getPokemonList(LIMIT).map { it.results }
}
```

If I do not use generic parameterized ViewModel, there is no need for delay. You can find repository at : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/Pokemon

Why do I need a delay, and what is the solution to avoid delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about the initializer's execution order of class. Here is the quote from [this article](https://medium.com/keepsafe-engineering/an-in-depth-look-at-kotlins-initializers-a0420fcbf546).

> First, default constructor arguments are evaluated, starting with
> argument to the constructor you call directly, followed by arguments
> to any delegated constructors. Next, initializers (property
> initializers and init blocks) are executed in the order that they are
> defined in the class, top-to-bottom. Finally, constructors are
> executed, starting with the primary constructor and moving outward
> through delegated constructors until the constructor that you called
> is executed. The constructor order is probably the most surprising,
> since no matter where in the class the constructor is defined, it is
> always executed after all initializers have run.

Please check the article for detailed information.

Comment: Thank you @Mustafa Kuloğlu, you are right. I have now transferred sendRequest() method to all child ViewModels init block, and it worked, but is there any cleaner solution where I don't have to rewrite init block in all child classes? Here are my ViewModels : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/Pokemon/tree/master/app/src/main/java/se/appshack/android/refactoring/viewmodels

Comment: @Ali You should try "constructor: instead of "init" in base class.

Comment: I tried secondary constructor as you mentioned but no succeed. Would you please show me in code how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Here is my solution: define requestObservable as a constructor parameter instead of abstract value in the base.  Than pass api.getPokemonList(LIMIT).map { it.results }
 as a Observable<List<NamedResponseModel>> to BaseViewModel's constructor in the MainViewModel instead of overridig.